# Customize tab in ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to add customized style to tabs of ngx-bootstrap for angular.
I want two things 
1)To remove the border line and 
2) To back-ground color to the active tab.

But nothing seems to work

### HTML Code

```
div >
<tabset>
   <tab customClass="customClass" heading="Home"></tab>
   <tab heading="Profile"></tab>
   <tab heading="About us"></tab>
</tabset>
</div>
```

## CSS Code

```
.customClass > a{
background-color:silver !important;
border-bottom: none !important;
outline: 0 !important; 
}

tab>active{
color:rgb(58, 45, 128)
}
```

What could be the solution ???

Comment: Did my answer help?

Comment: extremely sorry but no it didn 't help

Comment: Can you reproduce your issue on stackblitz?

Answer (score 6):

Try adding `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to your component metadata or use `::ng-deep` prefix

```
::ng-deep .customClass > a {
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ncxtk9?file=app%2Fapp.component.css)**

Answer (score 3):

If You want to Change CSS of Active tabs here is the CSS.Do not forget to Add !important

```
.modal-heading{
background-color: #038F43;
height: 30px;
color: #fff;
margin: 5px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.nav-tabs .nav-link{
background-color: #0d1323;
border: 1px solid #0d1323;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
}
.nav-tabs .nav-link:hover{
background-color: gray;
}

.nav-tabs .nav-link.active{
background-color: #038F43 !important;
color: #fff !important;
font-size: 12px;
}
.nav-tabs .nav-link.active:hover{
background-color: gray;
}



and Small change in .Ts File,Add encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None

import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-edit-golf-league-manager',
  templateUrl: './add-edit-golf-league-manager.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-edit-golf-league-manager.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
  })
```